# TODO list data structure beginner confuse

Tags: javascript, data-structures

All:

When I try to implement "TODO" app, there is a basic data structure question confuse me so much about the todos store:

Each Todo item is :

```
{
    id: todo id,
    content: pure text string
}
```

I am not sure if I should define an array to store this todo element or use JS object and use the id as the key? The feature provided by todo is:

- retrieve single todo item by id
- add new item to todo
- retrieve a bunch of todos base on how many we want to return
- add a bunch of todos(this operation could mix new todo and existing todo together)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the main difference is where order matters or not.

I mean, if the order matters, maybe an *array* is the preferred choice, for you can move around items and they are not tightly bound to their *id*.

On the other hand, if the order doesn't matter, a js object resembles more a *map* and it makes much sense to me, for you are simply associating a bunch of *parameters* to an *id*.

Comment: thanks, I guess I will just use hashmap like structure